# Como fazer uma busca dentro desse vetor de objetos?

Tags: java, array

Como eu faria a busca de um registro dentro do meu objeto?

O programa é uma agenda de contatos, e eu queria que ele fizesse a busca pelo nome que eu digitar em um JPane e retornasse os dados do contato buscado. Aqui está o código comentado.

```
package ExemploDeAula;

public class Agenda {
    //Define um vetor de objetos do tipo contato
    private Contato[] lstContatos;
    private int qtd;

    public void inicializar(){
        lstContatos = new Contato[10];
        qtd = 0;
    }

    public boolean inserir(Contato novoContato){
        // Verificar se não está cheio

        if (qtd>=10){ //se está cheio
            return false; //falhou
        }

        //atribuir o novoContato em uma posição livre
        else{
            lstContatos[qtd]= novoContato;
            qtd++;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean remover(Contato contato){
        return false;
    }

    public String pesquisar(String nome){
        int i;
        String dados;
        //procurar pelo nome entre os contatos e
        for (i=0;i<=qtd;i++){
            if (nome.equals(Contato.getNome())){

            }
        }
        //retornar o objeto correspondente
        return dados;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é fácil responder definitivamente só com este trecho, mas provavelmente eu mudaria isto:

```
public boolean pesquisar(String nome) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= qtd; i++) {
        if (nome.equals(lstContatos[i].getNome())) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Um erro é que não estava buscando o *array*. Outro erro é que o método que mais precisaria de um retorno de booleano está retornando algo que eu nem sei do que se trata. É para retornar uma *string*? Qual seria esta *string*? O próprio nome que eles está procurando? Não faz sentido.

Por outro lado se deseja realmente retornar o elemento achado:

```
public Contato pesquisar(String nome) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= qtd; i++) {
        if (nome.equals(lstContatos[i].getNome())) return lstContatos.[i];
    }
    return null;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/Search.java).

Tem uma série de pequenos "problemas" que parece existir neste código e que poderia ser feito melhor, mas a solução do problema específico é esta.

Comment: Sim, quero que ele retorne a String correspondente ao nome que ele procurou, como no array eu tenho uma posição para cada contato, ficaria fácil ele retornar o email e o telefone, que são os outros atributos da classe contato.

Comment: Retornar o que passou não faz sentido, mas se quer fazer, até funciona, entendeu o que deve fazer.

Answer (score 4):

Várias formas de pesquisar um array...

## Usando expressão regular

A rotina abaixo retorna os contatos cujo nome contém o valor passado por parâmetro:

```
public Contato[] pesquisarNomesParecidos(String nome) {
    return Arrays.stream(lstContatos, 0, qtd)
            .filter(c -> c.getNome().matches("(?i:.*" + Pattern.quote(nome) + ".*)"))
            .toArray(Contato[]::new);
}
```

Uso:

```
agenda.pesquisarNomesParecidos("os")
```

Funciona com:

- José
- Josias
- Osvaldo

## Sem considerar maiúsculas e minúsculas

```
public Contato[] pesquisarNomesIguais(String nome) {
    return Arrays.stream(lstContatos, 0, qtd)
            .filter(c -> c.getNome().equalsIgnoreCase(nome))
            .toArray(Contato[]::new);
}
```

Funciona com:

- FERNANDA
- fernanda
- Fernanda

## Retornando apenas um contato

Idem ao anterior, mas retornando apenas um, caso encontre:

```
public Optional<Contato> encontrarNomeIgual(String nome) {
    return Arrays.stream(lstContatos, 0, qtd)
            .filter(c -> c.getNome().equalsIgnoreCase(nome))
            .findFirst();
}
```

O uso de `Optional` serve para indicar que o contato pode ou não ser encontrado.

Se for encontrado, `Optional` vai conter o contato, senão o retorno será vazio (`Optional.empty()`).

Exemplo:

```
Optional<Contato> contato = agenda.encontrarNomeIgual("luiz");
if (contato.isPresent()) {
    contato.get().getNome();
} else {
    //não encontrado
}
```

## Retornar um sem `Optional`

Idem ao anterior, mas retornando `null` caso não encontre:

```
public Contato encontrarNomeIgualOuRetornaNulo(String nome) {
    return Arrays.stream(lstContatos, 0, qtd)
            .filter(c -> c.getNome().equalsIgnoreCase(nome))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

## Sem usar a API *streams*

Igual ao mencionado nas outras respostas, mas usei o `equalsIgnoreCase` ao invés de `equals`, assim não tem problemas com maiúsculas e minúsculas:

```
public Contato pesquisaSimples(String nome) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= qtd; i++) {
        if (nome.equalsIgnoreCase(lstContatos[i].getNome())) {
            return lstContatos[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

## Nome começando com o termo de busca

```
public Contato pesquisarComecandoCom(String nome) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= qtd; i++) {
        if (lstContatos[i].getNome().toLowerCase().startsWith(nome.toLowerCase()) {
            return lstContatos[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Uso:

```
agenda.pesquisarComecandoCom("fer")
```

Funciona com:

- FERNANDA
- fernanda
- Fernanda

Answer (score 2):

Como a pesquisa deveria retornar dados, vou adicionar uma resposta ligeiramente diferente.

De qualquer forma, a busca tem que ser realizada na lista de contatos e você precisaria adaptar a função getDados() para fazer exatamente o que você gostaria com os dados do contato.

```
public String pesquisar(String nome) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= qtd; i++) {
        if (nome.equals(lstContatos.getNome())) {
            return lstContatos.getDados();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom Gabriel, minha interpretação foi diferente, eu entendi que você pretende retornar o objeto com todas suas propriedades, mas com a condição de que você pesquise dentro de um array qual dos objetos possui o nome equivalente ao parâmetro passado que é o nome do contato, segue o método:

```
public Contato pesquisar(String nome) {
        Contato contatoRetorno = null;
        for (Contato contato : lstContatos) {
            if (contato.getNome().equals(nome)) {
                contatoRetorno = contato;
            }
        }
        return contatoRetorno;
    }
```

Segue um teste unitário para o método

```
public class Test {

    private Agenda agenda;
    private Contato contUm;
    private Contato contDois;
    private Contato contTres;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        agenda = new Agenda();
        agenda.setLstContatos(new Contato[3]);
        contUm = new Contato(1, "Maria");
        contDois = new Contato(2, "João");
        contTres = new Contato(3, "Cristiano");
        agenda.getLstContatos()[0] = contUm;
        agenda.getLstContatos()[1] = contDois;
        agenda.getLstContatos()[2] = contTres;
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        Contato contato = agenda.pesquisar("João");
        assertEquals(contato.getId(), 2);
    }

}
```